# Unable to capture network traffic for app installed on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried the following to capture the network traffic for an app installed on android emulator

Open Charles

Go to Proxy > SSL Proxy Settings...

Check “Enable SSL Proxying”

Select “Add location” and enter the host name and port (if needed)

Click ok and make sure the option is checked

Go to Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser..., and just follow the instruction.

use the Android's browser to download and install the certificate.)
In “Name the certificate” enter whatever you want
Click OK and you should get a message that the certificate was installed

Also configured the emulator to use the proxy settings for the wifi

I get the error

> Failure   Client SSL handshake failed: An unknown issue occurred
>   processing the certificate (certificate_unknown) Notes    You may need to
>   configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root
>   Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.

Comment: Are you on Android >= 7?